# Bounded type as method parameter?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I am trying to enforce a particular subclass type on an abstract method, like so:

```
public abstract class Searcher {    
  public abstract SearchResult search(<T extends SearchInput> searchInput);
}
```

This is to ensure that subclasses of Searcher have to extend a corresponding subclass of SearchInput.  I know I can use a bounded type for the method's return type, but I can't seem to get it to work as a method argument.  Is this possible in Java?

Comment: You need to declare the method's generic parameter first: `public abstract <T extends SearchInput> SearchResult search(T input)` - you declare it before the return type, not in the parameters. However, declare on how the type will be used, you may want to add the type parameter on the class itself, instead of the method.

Comment: That should be a generic parameter of the class, i.e. `public abstract class Searcher<T extends SearchInput> {` and then you can accept `T` in `search`. In subclasses, you do `class Subclass extends Searcher<SomeSearchInput>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html) on *Generic Methods*:

> The syntax for a generic method includes a list of type parameters, inside angle brackets, which appears before the method's return type.

You need:

```java
public abstract class Searcher {
    public abstract <T extends SearchInput> SearchResult search(T searchInput);
}
```

Point is, that generic type declaration must happen before the signature part.